# Rendering JSON in grails

Tags: json, grails

I use the following code to render data in JSON format.

```
render(contentType:"text/json") {
    results = array {
        db.eachRow(query) { row ->
            def rs = row.toRowResult()
            def a = b(rs.name,c,d)
            aMap.put("A",a) 
            pair(aMap)
        }
    }
    if (results) {
        status = "OK"
    }
    else {
        status ="Nothing present"
    }
}
```

The above code generates JSON in the following format

```
{
    "results": [
        {"A":"value1"},
        {"A":"value2"},
        ...................
        {"A":"valuen"}
    ],
    "status":"OK"
}
```

As u see above, the data is rendered as an **array of objects**. Is there a way I can render the results data as an **array of elements**. Like

```
{
    "results": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        ...................
        "valuen"
    ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way the JSON object is being built is quite obscure. What I like doing to render JSON responses in grails is creating a map or list in groovy and then use the `render` method just to convert it to JSON.

Doing the transformation of the `rowResult`'s inside the render method makes it quite confusing, I'd rather go for something like this

```
def results = db.rows(query).collect { rowResult ->
    b(rowResult.name, c, d) 
}
render(contentType: 'text/json') {[
    'results': results,
    'status': results ? "OK" : "Nothing present"
]}
```

I think it's more readable, and even shorter. This snippet gets you the desired result: no objects inside the `results` array, just strings.

Note the use of `rows`, which returns a list of RowResult's, eliminating the need to get it from the ResultSet's. The list is used to collect the transformed value `a` by calling `b` on each row's name. Collecting the elements doesn't imply creating a map (like in the `{  "A":"value1"}` JSON you were getting), just the same @will-buck achieved with the `<<` operator on a new, empty list.

All we do with the render method is declaring the `text/json` content type and passing it a literal map containing the keys `results` and `status`, which you want to write to the response. The conditional operator is used to concisely determine the status. It could also be used like this, by means of the JSON converter @will-buck also mentioned:

```
def responseData = [
    'results': results,
    'status': results ? "OK" : "Nothing present"
]
render responseData as JSON
```

Comment: I like your last code snippet better than the first one. It's probably more debugger-friendly also.

Comment: Yep, that JSON converter is definitely the way to go :)

Comment: Having issues with your last snippet in Grails 2.0. The response is rendered as text enclosed in `{}`.

Comment: @SAFX I don't know why I never saw this comment.
Anyway, it is enclosed in {} because that's how objects are enclosed in JSON: http://www.json.org/

Comment: what the need of "status" please ? is it to check manually (I mean like if(status==....){ ....} ) if something is found or it something grails/JS(client side ...) needs? ? thank you

Comment: It's not something Grails needs. It's part of the custom interface that the OP defined between server and client.

Answer (score 6):

Only off by a little bit :) Just need to change

```
aMap.put("A", a)
```

to be a collection or list, rather than a map. so something like

```
def aList = []
aList << a
```

Will get you what you want!

As a sidenote, there is a JSON converter in grails that will do that string building for you. Look into it [here](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference)

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough to render a JSON from controller:

```
render results as grails.converters.JSON
```