# render as JSON not working in Grails

Tags: grails, serialization

I am fairly new to Groovy and Grails and I am trying to create a method that returns a JSON formatted string.

I read a bit about Converters, and from what I can understand from a couple of sources([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639572/rendering-json-in-grails) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails11188/)) I should be able to do this:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class Record {

    //...

    private Map _metadata   = [:]

    String getMetadataJSON(){
        return render _metadata as JSON
    }
}
```

Not only this does not work, but the "render" keyword is not being resolved.

So my two questions are:

- Why is this not working and how should it be done?
- What kind of language construct is "render" supposed to be?, a closure?

Comment: the return is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` is used in a Controller within Grails and not (what appears to be) a Domain Class (in your example). If you want to get a JSON representation of something then simply:

```
String getMetadataJSON() {
  (_metadata as JSON)
}
```

The above will return a `String` representation in `JSON` format. Groovy doesn't require the `return` keyword.

Comment: So, what kind of language construct is "render"?

Comment: It's a method that is added to Controllers within Grails by the framework when something is identified as a Controller artifact during bootstrapping. It's added by either meta programming or traits (depending on version of Grails). You can find out more about it within the Grails documentation.

Comment: So the problem ended up being just type casting, in my testing I had to cast twice, first to a JSON object, then to a String object: `(record.metadata as JSON) as String == '{"one":2}'`